# Setting histogram breaks in ggplot2

Tags: r, ggplot2, histogram

I am new to ggplot2 and I am trying to obtain the same histogram that I would with `hist(results, breaks = 30)`.

How do I replicate the same histogram with ggplot2? I am playing with the `binwidth` parameter of the `geom_histogram`, but I am having a hard time making the two histograms look identical.

Comment: What code have you written so far?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you use the code you will see how the R decided to break up your data:

```
data(mtcars)
histinfo <- hist(mtcars$mpg)
```

From the `histinfo` you will get the necessary information concerning the breaks.

```
$breaks
[1] 10 15 20 25 30 35

$counts
[1]  6 12  8  2  4

$density
[1] 0.0375 0.0750 0.0500 0.0125 0.0250

$mids
[1] 12.5 17.5 22.5 27.5 32.5

$xname
[1] "mtcars$mpg"

$equidist
[1] TRUE

attr(,"class")
[1] "histogram"
>
```

Now you can tweak the code below to make your ggplot histogram, look more like the base one. You would have to change axis labels, scale and colours. `theme_bw()` will help you to get some settings in order.

```
data(mtcars)
require(ggplot2)
qplot(mtcars$mpg,
      geom="histogram", 
      binwidth = 5) +
    theme_bw()
```

and change the `binwidth` value to whatever suits you.
[image: histogram]

Comment: Great question, great answer. I have often wondered about this.

Answer (score 1):

Adding to *@Konrad*'s answer, instead of using `hist` you can use one of the `nclass.*` functions directly (see the `nclass` [documentation](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/grDevices/html/nclass.html)). There are three functions that are used by `hist`:

> `nclass.Sturges` uses Sturges' formula, implicitly basing bin sizes on
>   the range of the data.
>
> `nclass.scott` uses Scott's choice for a normal distribution based on
>   the estimate of the standard error, unless that is zero where it
>   returns 1.
>
> `nclass.FD` uses the Freedman-Diaconis choice based on the
>   inter-quartile range (`IQR`) unless that's zero where it reverts to
>   `mad(x, constant = 2)` and when that is 0 as well, returns 1.

The [`hist` function](http://stat.ethz.ch/R-manual/R-patched/library/graphics/html/hist.html) by default uses `nclass.Sturges`.